# How to import a .max model into Blender?

Tags: import, file-format

I've tried to import but I don't see the (.max) file as an option when importing. Is there another way to import the 3DMax model into Blender for rigging and animation?

Comment: so there is no way of getting a .max file into blender ?

Comment: Check http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/3DS_MAX_Scene_Interchange

Answer (score 24):

`.max` is the native internal format of 3DS Max, just like `.blend` is Blender's native format. To get models into blender use an interchange format such as Obj, Collada or FBX.

If you only have the `.max` file and no access to 3DS Max, then yes, there's no way to import it into blender, just like there's no way to import a `.blend` file into Max, or a `.max` file into Maya.

Comment: They don't import each other?! They're both from Autodesk!

Answer (score 9):

I haven't tried this myself, but there's a script available for download at http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/3DS_MAX_Scene_Interchange that says it'll convert a `.max` file into a `.scn` file that Blender can use.  The page has instructions on it.

Another thing you might try is just to use 3DS Max to export the `.max` file into something that Blender can read, like `.obj` (Wavefront) or `.dxf`, and import it into Blender from there.  Again, not sure how well it'll work, but it's worth a try.

You'll need a copy of the 3DS Max software for each of the above techniques.  There's a 30-day trial version on Autodesk's web site, and they also offer a monthly subscription package (just in case you can't afford the permanent license for the full version).

Answer (score 8):

This is an older question, but there don't seem to be any truly satisfactory answers yet. The suggestion to use 3DS Max to export to `.obj` or `.dxf` works fine if you have 3DS Max, but then it's pretty expensive.

A better solution is to convert the file using 3rd party software (which might not have been available in 2015 when this was last answered). A good one that I have found is [Yobi 3D](https://www.yobi3d.com/3d-file-convert), though there are others. This particular one is actually some kind of 3D model repository site, but has a converter that supports converting from `.3ds, .blend, .dae, .dwg, .dxf, .fbx, .ma, .max, .mb, .obj` to `.obj .stl .fbx .glb`. This makes it pretty useful for a number of conversions, and it's totally free to use.

Comment: Yobi 3D has shut down this January.

Answer (score 7):

I use max converter to OBJ using this site https://anyconv.com/max-to-obj-converter/

tried several times, for simple 3d model it should work, the conversion sometimes takes a while like 3 minutes or more

after downloaded the OBJ file, import using Blender
[image]

Comment: Didn't work. This is what it returned https://paste.ofcode.org/WMrs6sGm64YKDVZ6YNN84f or https://i.imgur.com/x0uNdgj.png after trying this model: https://free3d.com/3d-model/space-marine-war-hammer-81079.html

Comment: yes it's mostly not work. the best way is to open it in 3dsmax then re export to binary fbx or obj

Comment: it worked for me

Comment: Works for me too

Comment: simple object is OK but complex max file it's not possible

Answer (score 4):

I [converted the .max first to .obj](https://miconv.com/convert-max-to-fbx/).
Then I imported the .obj file into Blender.

Comment: Yobi3d has been shut down

Answer (score 1):

BMAX Converter addon. You require 3ds max too. Install plugins for both software.
https://titus.gumroad.com/l/B2MAX