# Maya compatibility

Tags: modeling, rigging, file-format, external-applications

I need to know if Blender will import Maya model files with Shaders and rigging?
I am having a model produced and they use Maya for rigging.

Comment: As you may know importing the shader isn't possible (or limited), since this depends on the render engine. However, exchanging the geometry works flawless via `.fbx` or `.obj` file format.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14808/how-to-import-a-max-model-into-blender

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting your models as a .fbx file that way Blender will know how to open it and read the file.   This question has been written alot of times though if you want to find other people's questions you can just go on google and look up "how to import Blender models to Maya" and you will get great results.

[How to Export "Selected Objects" to fbx in 2.77a](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50461/how-to-export-selected-objects-to-fbx-in-2-77a)