# How to Export "Selected Objects" to fbx in 2.77a

Tags: export

I just upgraded from blender 2.72 to 2.77, when trying to export a single model in the scene with the fbx exporter, the export options that exist in 2.72 are all gone. One of the most important ones is the "selected objects" option.
Am I missing something here?[image]

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, for some reason the UI scrolled all the way down, making it impossible to see the export options. After realizing that I scrolled back up and saw the options...