# How to Import 3ds max file into Blender?

Tags: rendering

I received the scene from a friend but cant seem to make it work properly in 3ds max
and when exporting as fbx into Blender it seems to lose all its materials and lights?

Comment: Importing files from other software is complicated. Actually you should see lights, cameras and basic material information, somtimes even textures. But this options have to be set in the 3DS Max FBX exporter. Maybe this is the reason.
Another reason can be: not all objects types are supported by FBX.
Hard to say what is the actual reason without knowing your content.

Comment: Heres the file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BEVAa8uSq5OTLu8G5EzeELz8iB3hBL2w/view

Do you think you could try loading it and show a screenshot of what it would look like on your end?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not able to read MAX files. See the answer by @JachymMichal . Maybe it helps. Ask your friend using other FBX settings or file types, like OBJ, DAE or GLTF.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14808/how-to-import-a-max-model-into-blender