# How to convert Max Character (with biped) to Blender Correctly

Tags: .fbx

[Max, FBX and Blender File](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgyAl3qkb-zOmIEsPASJK_0y592SuA?e=grImfG)

[image: In Blender]

I want to convert my max file to Blender, however, even if I already collapsed any modifier and clean all third-party plugin modifiers, Blender can not correctly convert my 3ds max file(fbx as well) and like image, IK can not be correctly converted and bones look so strange.

Though I try to use Mixamo, not helpful and I was more terrified that the file lost any data that can correctly show on-site and in Max.

How can I correct this trouble? If I have to use lots of steps to convert my model from Max to Blender, maybe I should give up on using Blender. I don't have any obligation for getting frustrated with it.

Comment: 1. You wrote *"Blender can not correctly convert my 3ds max file"*. What do you mean by this? Blender [doesn't read/convert 3DS Max files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14808/107598). -2- If you import an FBX file there are import options on the right side of the import dialog. At the bottom of the list, there is a section called *Armature*. There you can tick the option *[X] Automatic Bone Orientation". This will fix the bone orientation. -3- I can't see any IK mechanism. Has your model IK bones/joints in Max?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a .max model into Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14808/how-to-import-a-max-model-into-blender)

Comment: First, Automatic Bone Orientation is correct. However, I used Character Studio (Biped) for my character and it is already have IKs, but in Blender all of IKs are lost.

Comment: Maybe auto IK can temporarily solve problem, but not certainly. how to rebuild IK in this case?